# В inline-flex обрезается слово, а не переносится на новую строку - как исправить?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть 3 `inline-flex`. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при уменьшении экрана, когда слово не вмещается в 1 строку, вместо того, чтобы срабатывало разделение

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

и перенос на вторую строку, слово почему-то обрезается. Как это решить?

**Код**

```css
body {
  background: #F2F5F7;
}

.radio-inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 85px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-right: 1px dashed #C0C7DC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio-inline:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioblock">
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Direct Website</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Marketplace</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Two types</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex препятствует корректной работе word-wrap. Если нужно, чтобы переносились длинные слова, используйте inline-block либо принудительно расставляйте переносы в длинных словах с помощью `&shy;`

**Пример с inline-block**:

```js
function uniqueHeight() {
    let items = $('.radio-inline'),
  heights = [],
  tallest;
  
  function normalizeHeights() {
   items.each(function() {
    heights.push($(this).outerHeight()); 
   });
   tallest = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
   items.each(function() {
    $(this).css('min-height',tallest + 'px');
   });
  };
  normalizeHeights();

  $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function () {
   tallest = 0, heights.length = 0;
   items.each(function() {
    $(this).css('min-height','0');
   }); 
   normalizeHeights(); 
  });
 }
 uniqueHeight();
```

```css
body {
  background: #F2F5F7;
}
.radio-inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 35px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-right: 1px dashed #C0C7DC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.radio-inline:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radioblock">
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Direct WebsiteWebsite</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Marketplaceplace</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Two types</label>
</div>
```

**Пример с `&shy;`**:

```css
body {
  background: #F2F5F7;
}

.radio-inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 85px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-right: 1px dashed #C0C7DC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio-inline:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioblock">
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Direct Website</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Market&shy;place&shy;Market&shy;place</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype">Two types</label>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! Но, ваш пример с `inline-block` к сожалению, не универсальный - при уменьшении экрана, высота блока с 2мя строками увеличивается относительно других блоков, а должна сохраняться.
А с `&shy;` - это для небольших блоков и с доступом к коду хорошо, но если используется в больших блоках текста в постах, которые пишут копирайтеры, то это не вариант, как вы понимаете..

Comment: @Вася, ну, для inline-block можно придумать решение, чтобы высота подстраивалась. А насчёт `&shy` - это ж был пример для Вашего вопроса. У Вас в вопросе никаких больших блоков текста нет. В таком случае придётся придумывать какие-то "костыли", чтобы word-wrap работал с flex

Comment: "А насчёт &shy - это ж был пример для Вашего вопроса. "
@humster_spb да, для примера все ок - я его и зачел. Это была попытка порассуждать как найти универсальное решение: получается, что только костыль.
А поводу `inline-block` не совсем понял про какое решение вы говорите - на @media quaries просматривать высоту?

Comment: @Вася, нет, media quaries просматривать высоту - это плохой вариант. Можно добавить немного js, например (я дополнил ответ)

Answer (score 2):

`flex` не препятствует работе word-wrap, но иногда странно взаимодействует с textNode (текстом без обёртки). Можно использовать `<span>` для корректного переноса слов

```css
body {
  background: #F2F5F7;
}

.radio-inline {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 85px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-right: 1px dashed #C0C7DC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.radio-inline:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
.radio-inline span{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioblock">
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype"><span>Direct Website</span></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype"><span>Marketplace</span></label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radiotype"><span>Two types</span></label>
</div>
```