# CSS | Свойство float:left, блоки налазят друг на друга

Tags: html, css, style

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 create-news-left-block">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem
            ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor</p>

        <div class="block-left-helper">
            <h4>Помощь сервису в развитии</h4>
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                <?= Html::img('images/help-portal.png', ['alt' => 'logo']) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-left-helper">
            <h4>Прокачайте навыки журналиста</h4>
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                <?= Html::img('images/help-portal.png', ['alt' => 'logo']) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-left-helper">
            <h4>Поделитесь интересной новостью с нами</h4>
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                <?= Html::img('images/help-portal.png', ['alt' => 'logo']) ?>
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

я задаю для `block-left-helper-img` `float:left;`, чтобы текст отображался по правой стороне. Но получаю такой результат

[image: я]

Как правильно сделать, чтобы картинка была слева, текст - справа.
Никак не получается

Comment: зачем использовать float? используйте flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вроде так если я все правильно понял

```css
.block-left-helper-img{
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.block-left-helper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.block-left-helper-text{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 create-news-left-block">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem
            ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor</p>
        <div class="block-left">
        <div class="block-left-helper">
            
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                тут картинка
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
            <h4>Помощь сервису в развитии</h4>
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-left-helper">
            
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                тут картинка
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
            <h4>Прокачайте навыки журналиста</h4>
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-left-helper">
            
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                тут картинка
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
            <h4>Поделитесь интересной новостью с нами</h4>
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: какое отношение flex имеет к вопросу о поведении float?

Comment: как по мне так вопрос был: "Как правильно сделать, чтобы картинка была слева, текст - справа. Никак не получается", а не как с помощью float

Comment: "CSS | Свойство float:left, блоки налазят друг на друга" - вот как звучит вопрос

Comment: автор получил ответ, и думаю тут прав я

Comment: автору минус за это как и Вам

Comment: не знаю за что минус, если автор задал вопрос правильно и получил свой ответ, может заголовок вопроса немного не точный

Comment: Вы понимаете, что этот ресурс - прежде всего база знаний? Другой человек со схожей проблемой найдёт этот вопрос, а ответа не найдёт, потому что ответ Ваш вообще на другую тему и не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу и к проблеме. Он, может быть, решает данную конкретную задачу, но он не объясняет поведения float

Comment: @humster_spb, мне кажется, вы строго судите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1030297/256824

Answer (score 1):

Нужно задать блокам block-left-helper свойство clear: both - тогда они не будут наползать друг на друга

```css
.block-left-helper {
  clear: both;
}
.block-left-helper-img {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 create-news-left-block">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem
            ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor</p>

        <div class="block-left-helper">
            <h4>Помощь сервису в развитии</h4>
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-left-helper">
            <h4>Прокачайте навыки журналиста</h4>
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-left-helper">
            <h4>Поделитесь интересной новостью с нами</h4>
            <div class="block-left-helper-img">
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-left-helper-text">
                ewqkhj ehwqjoe
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.block-left-helper {
  clear: both;
}
```

либо `display:block`